# How change MutableLiveData value inside ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I need to change the value of MutableLiveData in my ViewModel, but I can't make it because the value is equal to null, I think need to establish an observer change it inside that, but I don't know how to do it and whether it's a good idea.

AudioRecordersListViewModel

```
class AudioRecordersListViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    var audioRecordsLiveData: MutableLiveData<MutableList<AudioRecordUI>> = MutableLiveData();
    private var audioRecordDao: AudioRecordDao? = null

    @Inject
    constructor(audioRecordDao: AudioRecordDao) : this() {
        this.audioRecordDao = audioRecordDao
        viewModelScope.launch {
        val liveDataItems = audioRecordDao
                .getAll().value!!.map { item -> AudioRecordUI(item) }
                .toMutableList()

            if (liveDataItems.size > 0) {
                liveDataItems[0].isActive = true
            }

            audioRecordsLiveData.postValue(liveDataItems)
        }
    }
}
```

AudioRecordDao

```
@Dao
interface AudioRecordDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM AudioRecordEmpty")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<MutableList<AudioRecordEmpty>>
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, using `!!` is not a good idea it can easily lead to NullPointer Exception, us `?` instead.

You can set an empty list on your LiveData and add new data to that List:

```
var audioRecordsLiveData: MutableLiveData<MutableList<AudioRecordUI>> = MutableLiveData();

init {
    audioRecordsLiveData.value = mutableListOf()
}
```

If you need to observe that LiveData:

```
mViewModel.mLiveData.observe(this, Observer { list ->
        if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
            //Update UI Stuff
        }
})
```

never set your LiveData inside Fragment/Activity

If you need to update your LiveData:

```
mViewModel.onSomethingHappened()
```

Inside ViewModel:

```
fun onSomethingHappened() {
  ...
  ...
  ...
  mLiveData.value = NEW_VALUE
}
```

If you want to update your LiveData from another thread use:

```
mLiveData.postValue()
```

Comment: I think `mLiveData` name should not start with "m" because it seems to be public in the `ViewModel`. https://source.android.com/docs/setup/contribute/code-style#follow-field-naming-conventions